# How do I find associated records for a record found by slug with Friendly ID?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

I have implemented Friendly IDs and right now I am having trouble associating the opportunities for a company by slug (I had this working fine by ID).

CompaniesController:

```
  def show
    @opportunities = Opportunity.where("company_id = ?", params[:id]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 25)
  end
```

The Opportunity model has a company_id column. (Company has_many Opportunities).  So the above works perfectly is my URL is "companies/1".

Since I've implemented Friendly ID, I now have a "slug" column in my Company model. So essentially I need to match the Company ID to the Opportunity ID, then grab the slug?

I am trying something like this, but it is not working:

```
  def show
    @opportunities = Opportunity.where("company_id = ?", params[:id]).find(params[:slug]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 25)
  end
```

How should I actually be doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use friendly finds, something like this

```
def show
  @company = Company.friendly.find(params[:id])
  @opportunities = @company.opportunities.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 25)
end
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I always try to make it more difficult than it is! Thanks very much.